# Linq List to string with comma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, linq

I have this code.

```
 var userListResult = from user in userList
                             from role in user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles
                             where role.Id == ((int)model.Roles).ToString()
                             select new UserManageViewModel.UserViewModel()
                             {
                                 Id = user.UserId,
                                 Email = user.AspNetUsers.Email,
                                 Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                                 IsAdviser = user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.AsQueryable().Any(r => r.Id == ((int)eCareRoles.Adviser).ToString()),
                                 IsAdmin = user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.AsQueryable().Any(r => r.Id == ((int)eCareRoles.Admin).ToString()),
                                 Company = user.UserCompanies != null ? user.UserCompanies.Name : String.Empty,
                                 Role = model.Roles,
                                 ListIfRoles = user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.Select(x => x.Name).Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j)

                             };
```

I need to get in ListIfRoles string with comma. But I always get error 
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I tried string.Join(",", list), tried convert to Array and then Join or Aggregate - but it always error.

Also i tried this`user.

```
AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.Select(x => x.Name).AsEnumerable().Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j)
```

But error again. 
    Help please.

Comment: `string.Join(",", user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray())` - Join takes an array.

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score -2):

you can try,

```
String.join(",",user.AspNetUsers.AspNetRoles.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray())
```

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."